# How to cut range of characters from multiple columns

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep, cut

I have a tab delimited file which looks like this:

```
CHROM <TAB> POS <TAB> AD0062-C <TAB> AD0063-C <TAB> AD0065-C <TAB> AD0074-C 
2L <TAB> 440 <TAB>0/1:63:60,0,249 <TAB>0/1:89:86,0,166 <TAB>1/1:96:107,24,0<TAB>1/1:49:42,6,0  
2L <TAB> 260<TAB>0/1:66:63,0,207<TAB> 1/1:99:227,111,0<TAB>1/1:99:255,144,0<TAB> 1/1:49:42,6,0
2L <TAB> 595 <TAB> 0/1:11:85,0,8 <TAB>0/1:13:132,0,10 <TAB>0/1:73:70,0,131<TAB> 0/1:59:72,0,56
```

I want to select only the first 3 characters starting from column 3 so that I can get an output that looks like this:

```
CHROM <TAB> POS <TAB> AD0062-C <TAB> AD0063-C <TAB> AD0065-C <TAB> AD0074-C 
2L <TAB> 440 <TAB> 0/1 <TAB> 0/1 <TAB> 1/1 <TAB> 1/1  
2L <TAB> 260 <TAB> 0/1 <TAB> 1/1 <TAB> 1/1 <TAB> 1/1
2L <TAB> 595 <TAB> 0/1 <TAB> 0/1 <TAB> 0/1 <TAB> 0/1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`. For every line but first one and if it has more that two fields, get substring of them. The `print` command it is for every line because it has no condition.

```
awk '
    BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }
    NF > 2 && FNR > 1 { 
        for ( i=3; i<=NF; i++ ) { 
            $i = substr( $i, 1, 3 ) 
        } 
    } 
    { print }
' infile
```

Output:

```
CHROM   POS     AD0062-C        AD0063-C        AD0065-C        AD0074-C 
2L      440     0/1     0/1     1/1     1/1
2L      260     0/1     1/1     1/1     1/1
2L      595     0/1     0/1     0/1     0/1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `GNU sed`. From second line until last one, substitute all characters between tabs with the first three at the beginning, and do it many times in each line but only from second match (avoiding first two fields):

```
sed '2,$ s/\([\t]...\)[^\t]*/\1/2g' infile
```

Output:

```
CHROM   POS     AD0062-C        AD0063-C        AD0065-C        AD0074-C 
2L      440     0/1     0/1     1/1     1/1
2L      260     0/1     1/1     1/1     1/1
2L      595     0/1     0/1     0/1     0/1
```

Comment: Note that `2g` works as described in GNU `sed` (which you specified). In other implementations, it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1b;s/\(\S\{3\}\)\S*/\1/2g' file
```